# I cant select this specific ID in Jquery and Meteor

Tags: jquery, css, select, meteor

I got this

```
<template name="showBacklinks">
<div class="col-md-6" id="backlinkcontainer" role="main">
        <h1>Backlinks</h1>
            <ol>
                {{#each url}}
                <div class="magicshit">
                <li><a href="{{backurl}}">{{backurl}}</a>
                <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </li></div>
                {{/each}}
            </ol>
</div>
```

I want that when I click the button the current li where I clicked will get the `class="magictime puffOut"` but I always select the wrong things..

Heres my Jquery/Meteor code:

```
    Template.showBacklinks.events({
    'click #delete': function(){
        var x = this._id;
        $(this).addClass('magictime puffOut', function(){
            Backlinks.remove(x);
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $(this) you have to target the DOM element using the passed in event, like so:

```
Template.showBacklinks.events({
'click .delete': function(event){
    var x = this._id;
    $(event.target).addClass('magictime puffOut', function(){
        Backlinks.remove(x);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly add the `magictime puffout` classes to the `li` element associated with a clicked `button`, I would suggest defining your event handler like so:

```
Template.showBacklinks.events({
    'click .delete': function(event, template) {
        var buttonControl = event.currentTarget;
        var $listItemElement = $(buttonControl.parentNode);
        var idToRemove = this._id;
        $listItemElement.addClass('magictime puffout', function() {
            // Remove element from collection
            Backlinks.remove(idToRemove);
        });
    }
});
```

Notice, similar to the other answers, this event handler uses `delete` as a class rather than as an ID on the button since it is possible for there to be more than one of the buttons rendered in the template. Also, different from the other answers, this solution references the `li` element properly through the `button` control by using the `parentNode` attribute of a given HTML element. Finally, be sure to remove the document by ID from the relevant collection.

EDIT: Combined another answer with mine to create best answer for this question.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it not wait with the removing. Meteor updates faster than the puffOut effect. And I am too stupid to change it in your example :(

Comment: It would be entirely possible to add a `setTimeout()` call to it then. Determine the length of time that thr animation takes to effect it's changes and set the timeout length for that. Then the collection document can be safely removed.

Comment: The answer of Ramsay, there it works without setTimeout. I think because its in an function? But I dont know how insert this in your example

Comment: As far as I know, the jQuery `addClass()` function does not have a two parameter version, only two one parameter signatures. The suggestion that he mas hade would not work.

Comment: I see. Good, I'm glad that you found a workable solution! :-)

Comment: No I mean the solution from Ramsay works for using the animation, but it only removes the button not the whole <li>, I need combinate your both solutions, but I dont know how :(

Comment: I have modified my answer to include Ramsay's suggestion of using the callback function in the `addClass()` jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `id` for every item that the templates `{{#each}}` loop is generating; the `id` tag is meant to be unique throughout the entire document. Remove the `id` and replace it with a delete class and use that as your selector and see?

```
class="btn btn-default delete"

Template.showBacklinks.events({
    'click .delete': function(){
```

Comment: It still not work. I tried it with classes before too, the IDs I just tried because I am desperate :(